# Error creating executable with py2app expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, macos, executable, py2app

I'm trying to create an executable with py2app but I get this error, I'm not sure how to fix it and I'm not sure if I'm including all the files correctly.

My working directory looks like this:

```
directory
  -- app_icon.png
  -- app_loading.gif
  -- app_logo.png
  -- detector.pb
  -- model.py
  -- myapp.py
  -- VGG16_weights.h5
  -- VGG16.h5
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['myapp.py']
DATA_FILES = ['app_icon.png', 'app_loading.gif', 'app_logo.png', 'VGG16.h5', 'VGG16_weights.h5', 'detector.pb']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    py_modules=['model'],
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

My application runs correctly when I do python myapp.py, however after I create an executable using

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

when I run

```
./dist/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
```

the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luis/Desktop/py2appexec/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 450, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/luis/Desktop/py2appexec/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 444, in _run
    exec(compile(source, script, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/luis/Desktop/py2appexec/myapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    import model as custom_model
  File "/Users/luis/Desktop/py2appexec/model.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/luis/virtualenvironment/executable/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 732, in <module>
    plugin_dir = _os.path.join(s, 'tensorflow-plugins')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
2020-01-20 11:06:20.690 myapp[3806:164925] myapp Error
```

It seems like it is getting null when looking for a path but I don't know why or how to fix it, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What packages are in your `py` files? Maybe you can try adding the packages to your `setup.py` file. For example, I have this in my `OPTIONS` variable:

```
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages':['pygame']}
```

I would also try looking in the `/Users/luis/Desktop/py2appexec/dist/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/` and look at the files mentioned to see if something is missing. I was missing images, although I think your issue might be a little bit different. Once I added the images to the folder, it worked fine.